# How to get cpu sirq in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, embedded-linux, sh

Following is the output of `top -b`

```
Mem: 95752K used, 29164K free, 0K shrd, 0K buff, 35176K cached
CPU:   5% usr   9% sys   0% nic   0% idle   0% io   0% irq  84% sirq
```

I need to continuously monitor the `sirq`, how can I do that in the shell script(sh) ?

Regards,
Yuvi

Comment: `top` is suggested for momentary performance. If you want to monitor something along the time, you'd better use `sar`. This thread can help you --> http://www.unix.com/solaris/117258-monitoring-output-top-command-hourly-basis.html

Comment: @fedorqui  that was the output of top. I need to grep only sirq value `(84)`

Answer (score 1):

See **section 1.8** of the Linux Kernel [proc.txt document](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).  Also instructive is the [busybox top source](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/procps/top.c).
  From **section 1.8** of the *proc.txt* document,

> ### 1.8 Miscellaneous kernel statistics in /proc/stat
>
> Various pieces   of  information about  kernel activity  are  available in the
>   /proc/stat file.  All  of  the numbers reported  in  this file are  aggregates
>   since the system first booted.  For a quick look, simply cat the file.
>
> The "softirq" line gives counts of softirqs serviced since boot time, for each
>   of the possible system softirqs. The first column is the total of all
>   softirqs serviced; each subsequent column is the total for that particular
>   softirq.

So the following command gets the total since booting,

```
cat /proc/stat | grep softirq | awk '{print $2}'
```

You have to do some math in your script to get a *delta*.

Each `CPU` line has a *softirq* value.  It is the eighth item and again manually delta the *time*.

```
cat /proc/stat  | grep cpu[^0-9] | awk '{ print $8}'
```

You can select each **CPU** individually if you like.  I am sure people can come up with better scripts, but I think they show the principal.

Answer (score 0):

i would use c

using a fork() a pipe() and an execl()

1.create pipe()

2.do a fork()

3.son. treats execl() output and sends to pipe

4.father. waits, receives and displays desired field

all this on a loop